# Robot Framework - Soap Request - Variable

Tags: soap, robotframework

- I have a json data in soap request (snippet below) in robot framework and when I use a variable - It is not getting resolved - I have bold out the variable used in the request. I tried using {TRANSACTIONID} and {"TRANSACTIONID"} but did not work. Can anybody please let me know. Appreciate your help!! Thanks

Here is the robot framework request:

```
Send Start Request
[Arguments]  ${abc}  ${abc1}  ${abc2}  ${abc3}  
${start_request}
sleep    ${Delay}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  2 min  10 sec  Create Soap Client  & 
{login_details}[url]/soap/v1/CentralSystemService16Soap12?wsdl
sleep    ${Delay}
${message}=  Create Raw Soap Message  ${str}
sleep    ${Delay} 
${soap_response}=  Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   2 min  10 sec  Call Soap 
Method  StartTransaction     ${message}
${transactionID}=  Get Wsdl Object Attribute  ${soap_response}  
transactionId
${ID}  Convert To String    ${transactionID}
Set Suite Variable  ${ID}
```

==

## Soap Request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:ns="urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/"><soap:Header 
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><ns:data>{"transactionId": 
{TRANSACTIONID},"connectorId": 1,"mobileNumber": "+12323234345", 
"emailAddress": "xyz@gmail.com"}</ns:data></ns:dataTransferRequest> 
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

==

## Soap Resonse

```
<ns:data>{&quot;transactionId&quot;:{&quot;TRANSACTIONID&quot;},&quot;} 
</ns:data>
```

Comment: Could you please try to improve the formatting of your question? It's hard to read. Also, please show actual robot code that you're using to make the request.

Comment: Bryan - I got to format the question and provided the required code. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Bryan - Please let me know if you need more information - Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, I had the same issue this morning. Do you remember if you are able to solve it in these last 12 months?